# Function call using a for loop to cycle through array not working, Help please

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, dynamic

I'm very new to Javascript but I have a problem which I have spent all day trying to research and solve, like to do it myself but i'm very stuck.

My code is simple, I have created 5 functions, 1 tests for letters, one tests for numbers, 1 for an open bracket and 1 for a closed bracket, and the fifth spots a full stop.  These functions return true.

I then created a function to call all of these functions when required to produce a numerical output depending on what is found in a text string.

Back to the top, I have a string, I created an array using split to place each of the characters in the string into the separate addresses in the array. The idea is that I use a for loop to scroll through the array and output the type into identity, which is then outputted in a list.

The issue is it will do the loop once then crash, and i can't find the problem, the issue lies in the line:

```
identity = isWhat(ModCompound[x],ModCompound[y]);
```

removing it with // and the for loop runs fine.

I would like to know why? what is the mistake?

code: (raw FORM)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Sjb 19/03/2015
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        Chemicals
</br>

    Compound: <input id="compound" value="NaCl.2(H20)">


<script>
    var identity;
    var x;
    Compound = document.getElementById('compound').value;

    ModCompound = Compound;
    ModCompound = ModCompound.split('');

    for (i = 0; i < Compound.length; i++){
        x = i;
        y = i;
        document.write(i);
        identity = isWhat(ModCompound[x],ModCompound[y]);

        document.write(Math.random() + "   : " + identity + "</p>");

    }    

      ModCompound= ModCompound.join('');

    // Custom Functions
        function isWhat(n1,c1)                        //OUTPUT 1,2,9,0,8
        {
            if (isLetter(n1,c1) === true) {          
                return isWhat = 1;
                //document.write = "L";
            }           //OUTPUT 1
            if (isNumber(n1,c1) === true) {           
                return isWhat = 2;
                //document.write = "N";
            }           //OUTPUT 2
            if (isOpenBracket(n1,c1) === true){       
                return isWhat = 9;
                //document.write("OB");
            }       //OUTPUT 9
            if (isClosedBracket(n1,c1) === true) {    
                return isWhat = 0;
                //document.write = "CB";
            }    //OUTPUT 0
            if (isFullStop(n1,c1) === true) {         
                return isWhat = 8;
                //document.write = "FS";

        }         //OUTPUT 8
        }

        function isNumber(n, c)                     //OUTPUT(s) TRUE
        {
          if (n >= 0 || n <= 9 ) {
          //document.write(n + "   N   " + c + "</p>");
          return isNumber = true;
        }  
    } 
        function isLetter(n, c)
        {
          n = n.charCodeAt(0);
          if (((n >= 65) && (n <= 90)) || ((n >= 97) && (n <= 122))) { 
          //document.write(n + "   L   " + c + "</p>");
          return isLetter = true;
        }  
    } 
        function isOpenBracket(n,c)
        {
          if (n === "(")  {
          //document.write(n + "   OB   " + c + "</p>");
          return isOpenBracket = true;
        }  
    }
        function isClosedBracket(n,c)
        {
          if (n === ")")  {
          //document.write(n + "   CB   " + c + "</p>");
          return isClosedBracket = true;
        }  
    }
        function isFullStop(n,c)
        {
          if (n === ".")  {
          //document.write(n + "   F   " + c + "</p>");
          return isFullStop = true;
        }  
    }



  </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your return statements should just be like this:

```
return 1;
```

You're writing this:

```
return isWhat = 1;
```

That's setting the variable `isWhat` to `1`, then returning it. `isWhat` is a function, though, so setting it to `1` makes is so you can't call it (because now it's a number, not a function). Also, there's no need to type `var===true`, because if the variable is true, then `var` will evaluate to `true` and the `if` statement will run.

Comment: So annoying when it turns out to be something so simple.  Thank you very much i will continue to plug away.  embarrasing how long ive been messing about with that one!!!